# Need to write Test Class...for get Methd

Tags: community, sandbox, salesforce-id

I am at beginning level in salesforce..

I need to write test class for a class in which i have confused how to go with get method code coverage..Can anybody help..

Please see my class method as below:

```
public List<Orderc> getorders() {

 disp = True;
 for(ProcessInstanceWorkitem  Workitemids: [Select id,p.ProcessInstance.Status,p.ProcessInstanceid, p.ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId,p.processInstance.CompletedDate,p.ActorId, p.OriginalActorId,p.processInstance.targetobject.type from ProcessInstanceWorkitem p where p.processInstance.targetobject.type = 'Order']) {

                workitemmap.put(Workitemids.ProcessInstanceid,Workitemids);

        }

        for(ProcessInstanceStep steps : [Select id,p.ActorId,p.processInstanceid,p.processInstance.id,processInstance.targetobject.type from 
                                      ProcessInstanceStep  p where p.processInstance.targetobject.type = 'Order' AND p.stepstatus = 'Approved' AND p.Actorid =:UserInfo.getUserId()]) {

                LastActoridmap.put(steps.processInstance.id,steps);


        }

    if(OrderList == null) {
        OrderList = new List<Orderc>();


         TargetIDList= new List<ID>();
         Map<string ,ProcessInstanceNode  > mapname = new Map<string,ProcessInstanceNode  >();
         Map<string ,ProcessInstanceNode  > approvedmapname = new Map<string,ProcessInstanceNode  >();


             for(ProcessInstanceNode  p: [Select id,p.ProcessInstance.Status,p.NodeStatus,p.lastactor.name, p.ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId,p.processInstance.CreatedDate,CompletedDate ,p.LastActorId,p.processInstance.targetobject.type from ProcessInstanceNode p WHERE p.processInstance.TargetObject.type = 'order' AND p.processInstance.Status = 'Pending'   order by CompletedDate desc LIMIT :blockSize OFFSET :index]) {




            TargetIDList.add(p.ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId);
            if(mapname.get(p.ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId) == null)
               mapname.put(p.ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId,p);
            if(approvedmapname.get(p.ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId) == null && p.nodestatus == 'Approved')
               approvedmapname.put(p.ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId,p);


        }


        Map<id,order> ordermap = new Map<id,order>([select Id,Account.Name,OrderNumber,BR_Brand__c,BR_RegionName__c,BR_TotalAmount__c,BR_DistrictName__c,BR_Currency__c,BR_TotalConvertedQuantity__c, Name from Order where id in :TargetIDList  ]);



         for(ProcessInstanceNode  p: mapname.values()){

            // As each order is processed we create a new orderc object and add it to the OrderList

            if(orderMap.get(p.ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId) != null && workitemmap.get(p.ProcessInstanceid).ActorId == userinfo.getuserid()){
                orderc ordp = new orderc();
                ordp.ord = orderMap.get(p.ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId);
                ordp.pro = p;


                if(workitemmap.get(p.ProcessInstanceid) != null)
                    ordp.workitemid = workitemmap.get(p.ProcessInstanceid).id;

                     if(mapname.get(p.ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId) != null)
                     if(approvedmapname.get(p.ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId) != null){
                         ordp.lastapprovername = approvedmapname.get(p.ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId).LastActor.name;
                             ordp.lastapproverid = approvedmapname.get(p.ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId).LastActorid;
                    }



                OrderList.add(ordp); 
            }
            TargetIDList.add(p.ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId);

        } 


        totalRecs = [Select Count() from Order where id in :TargetIDList];
    }

    disp = False;
    return OrderList;
}
```

if anybody can give me any sample code or startup to this.

Really appriciats your response on this...thanks..

Comment: Are you able to include what you've written so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@istest private static void myUnitTest() {
  //setup test data
  ...
  MyClass foo = new MyClass();
  Test.StartTest();
  List<Order__c> orders = foo.getorders();
  Test.StopTest;
  //make useful assertions on orders
}
```

Where it says setup test data, you'll want to create and insert SObjects that satisfy different conditions in your logic. After the test, you can then assert that these records were retrieved (or not retrieved) as expected.

Comment: Thaks for your promt response..I have used the below code in test calss:          
 @isTest(SeeAlldata=true)
public class Br_MassOrderApprovalTest {
      
    public static testMethod void VerifyOrders() {
       
  Br_OrderwrapperClassController foo = new Br_OrderwrapperClassController();
       
  Test.StartTest();
  List<Orderc> orders = foo.getorders();
        
  Test.stopTest();
        
        
        //make useful assertions on orders
        System.assertNotEquals(' ',orders.get(0));
  
}
        
        
        
    }

Comment: I would recommend not using @isTest(SeeAlldata=true)  if possible.  Instead, you should setup your data in your test class.  I'll update my answer to give an example